# Como pegar 4 últimos números de uma variável?

Tags: java, variáveis

Tenho que pegar últimos números de uma variável e eu não sei como fazer. Estou pegando os milissegundos e preciso jogar nessa variável `lol`, onde preciso que retorne só os últimos 4 dígitos de `lol` não ela inteira.

```
package trabalho01;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class aleatorio {

    public int aleatoriar() {       
        Calendar lCDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int lol = (int) (lCDateTime.getTimeInMillis());     
        return lol;
    }
}
```

Comment: A resposte te ajudou de alguma forma? Você sabe como funciona o *site*? Sabe que pode aceitar uma resposta que resolve o seu problema? E pode votar em tudo o que for útil para você no *site*. Veja o[tour].

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar o [operador de módulo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) para pegar o resto da divisão de 10 (nossa base numérica) elevado a 4 (os dígitos que você quer pegar), ou seja, 10000.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(aleatoriar());
    }
    public static int aleatoriar() {       
        Calendar lCDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        return (int)(lCDateTime.getTimeInMillis() % 10000);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZaSVbt). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/whvjozdh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/GetLastDigits.%2Cjava).

A variável intermediária é desnecessária (quando tem dificuldade de dar um nome significativo para ela, provavelmente ela não é útil).